# Get reach/likes from Instagram API with followers/non followers info

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to retrieve IG post's metrics information with the new additional data about followers/non_followers (recently added on the platform's APP).
At the moment I have a FB app connected to my Instagram business account and I read metrics like reach,impressions,engagement etc as lifetime values:

```
{
    "name": "reach",
    "period": "lifetime",
    "values": [
                {
                    "value": 651177
                }
            ],
    "title": "Reach",
    "description": "Total number of unique accounts that have seen the media object",
            "id": "myId/insights/reach/lifetime"
        },
```

Is there a way to get them with a kind of breakdown, like for the FB Api? Didn't find anything on the docs, and by trying with the [GraphApi Tool Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) I couldn't find more fields/breakdowns for this endpoint. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!